Should moderators delete AI-generated questions in Staging Ground?
As per the current policy (MSO, Help Center), it is not allowed to use AI tools to create content for Stack Overflow. This notably does not exclude questions.
Normally, moderators delete posts that are found in violation of this ban.
In Staging Ground however things feel different. The declared purpose of Staging Ground is to groom questions into a state that is suitable for publication.
It seems more constructive for a moderator to inform the OP about site policies and ask them to rewrite the question in their own words, instead of outright deleting it. The Staging Ground review task then would be completed with "Require Major Changes".
Note that:

this question is different from
Can authors completely rewrite their Staging Ground posts? as we do not suggest to rewrite the question into a totally different one. We only ask the OP to reword it, much like we would handle a question that is not in English;
this post does not imply anything about flagging, that can be discussed separately.


Assuming these questions don't have to be deleted, I guess normal reviewers can do the same.

How would the moderation team ensure that the AI content is removed before the post is able to be approved? At the moment (in my opinion) the approval system is somewhat broken, as a single user can override many people's opinion with an approval vote; no matter how many people, or who, have previously marked a post needing major changes, is off topic, etc. how would the moderators stop users approving such posts while they still contain AI content?

Or the auto graduation feature of the staging ground could also publish content that is AI generated then. Why not start again in the SG without AI content? Can users still see their deleted questions, if they need to remember them? I hope so. "It seems more constructive for a moderator to inform the OP about site policies and ask them to rewrite the question in their own words, instead of outright deleting it." That might also be something for the main site. Like give them 24 hours everywhere to rewrite or they get deleted.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I think forcing mods to come back to flagged questions after 24h could be a lot of unnecessary work.

@dan1st I guess so too, although an automatic timer and automatic reflagging could go a long way. One could even do automatic delayed deletion if no edit occurred within 24 hours and only if one occurred, a second review flag. It would require changes to flagging though, so unlikely unfortunately. But if it is more constructive, it still might be a good idea in principle.

How could anyone say that a question was AI generated and not machine translated or something else? Questions only quality that matters is their ability to produce answers. Forcing the asker to use words they aren't used to and therefore making undesirable to ask the question they want to ask seems like busywork.

Do AI-generated questions have the same problems as AI-generated answers? Do they fail to reflect the author's true question and tend to be nonsense? I don't have any idea because, as far as I know, I've never seen one. Perhaps it's better to call them AI-assisted questions.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk - Yes; They are not allowed

Ummm, yes? Why do you even have to ask that? | Honestly, if you have problems writing a coherent answer, having a machine do it for you won't help you get any better at it. I really don't see a reason why we should support that sort of nonsense.

@DanMašek The "Why ask this" can be answered with "because the Staging Ground is different from the main site in many ways and it's for improving questions with the asker". These questions aren't published on the main site so it seems reasonable to think about using Staging Ground mechanisms to deal with posts that shouldn't go to the main site.

@dan1st Sure, but the question is, what sort of stuff do we actually want to try to salvage there? Just because it's meant to deal with lower quality posts that would get close, does it mean that we should try to recover everything? Even someone just taking a literal dump there?

AI-generated questions violate the sitewide ban against such content, and should be deleted. Users who post AI-generated answers don't get the option to rewrite them - they are deleted immediately. The Staging Ground shouldn't be any different. Spam that is submitted via the Staging Ground is also summarily deleted as such, without offering the author an opportunity to rewrite them.

I kind of disagree with this on the basis that AI questions seem significantly less harmful than AI answers (although the site policy doesn't really make the distinction). It's kind of assumed that the person asking the question is somewhat uninformed about the topic (otherwise they wouldn't need to ask)

Which isn't to argue for a complete free-reign on AI questions. e.g. My personal frustration with AI-generated questions is when they have a fictional "what I have tried" section (because that's what it believes a good question should have) when of course they haven't tried anything.

I need to disagree with you here @DavidW - AI questions are about as harmful as SPAM (and I'd argue that AI answers exceed the harm that SPAM does). As you said yourself, AI questions make it impossible to distinguish what comes from the user (i.e. what they really want to do, what code they have, what they have tried) and what the LLM has added/imagined/hallucinated. Playing "telephone" with a LLM in the middle does not lead to good - or even answerable - questions. We have plenty of "bad" questions, no need to further pollute the pool by adding "good looking" ones that are actually worse.

@CharonX: We don't need an AI to generate good looking bad questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79138087/14768

While I'll acknowledge the consensus on this answer by accepting it, the argument is rather shallow. I believe the issue can't be dismissed just by invoking the current "No AI" policy, it is more nuanced than that. Thom A's answer reaches the same conclusion but with a more compelling and well-presented argument.

I agree with Ken White's answer and these posts should be deleted, however, I wanted to add a different view point as well, based on the comment I posted:

How would the moderation team ensure that the AI content is removed before the post is able to be approved? At the moment (in my opinion) the approval system is somewhat broken, as a single user can override many people's opinion with an approval vote; no matter how many people, or who, have previously marked a post needing major changes, is off topic, etc. how would the moderators stop users approving such posts while they still contain AI content?

I agree with the sentiment that the Staging Ground (SG) is a place to improve questions so that they meet to guidelines and rules of the site before they go to the main site and, in an ideal world, is a user did post a question generated by AI then we could put it into a "Needs Major Changes" state until such time that it isn't AI. Unfortunately, like many areas of the site, we "can't have nice things". For such a feature to work it would need a "mod level" "Needs Major Changes" status, so that other users cannot approve the post; such a feature doesn't exist.
Moderators delete posts that break the rules, be that AI, plagiarism, etc, and can't be (easily) redeemed. That, however, does not mean an author can't redeem them, but when a post is moderator deleted only a moderator can undelete it. This is important as it means that the "average" curator can't vote to undelete a post that has fallen afoul of the rules but it isn't immediately obvious. AI posts definitely fit in this category, as for many they can be difficult to identify.
For an answer (or question) on the main site, a post can be custom mod flagged for undeletion if it's made to be appropriate for the site. I don't, however, really see the benefit of this in the SG. I would, in truth, rather see the author try again, properly; going through the motions of writing a good question to start with, trying to create a MRE (if appropriate), and providing all the content they can. This is very likely the best way a user new to asking will learn how to ask; by doing to process properly.
Also, unlike posts that do get to the main site, I suspect that deleted posts in the SG weigh far less on the ban algorithm; at worst they are 0 score deleted posts. As such posting again is much less of an issue compared to trying to salvage a (mod) deleted AI generated question with a score of -3 or something, which could quickly help a user get to a question ban.
As for introducing "Mod Level" statuses in the SG, so that a single user can't approve a post when it's in "moderator jail", though I think this could be a good feature, I also don't hink it's worth the time investment. There are many more things I would rather the SO Staff spend their time on (compared to stuff they are wasting their time on), and the moderators have enough to do as it is. Adding another task to their (the moderator's) workload seems unwise.
So yes, please do just delete the posts, and provide the author with the same information you do for other users that post such content.


Should moderators delete AI-generated questions in Staging Ground?

Yes. AI-generated content is content that will never be of the quality to appear on Stack Overflow. That is the primary reason why such content is banned here.

It seems more constructive for a moderator to inform the OP about site policies and ask them to rewrite the question in their own words, instead of outright deleting it.

No, for the same reason I gave in my previous paragraph.

I will repeat what I have said before, because it seems that people are incapable of remembering it:
It is always the duty of the user posting a question to ensure that question complies with the Stack Overflow rules, and is written in a manner to make it as easily answerable as possible.
It is not the duty of curators to hand-hold and babysit and beg and cajole and vainly hope that a user will panel-beat their train wreck of a question into something answerable.
I am sick to death of this nonsensical molly-coddling mentality that every user is a good person who deserves to be treated as if every action they perform is a gift from $diety, and any rule they violate should be treated as if they are a toddler who made a whoopsie in their diaper. Because we are not talking about toddlers, we are talking about teenagers and adults who have agency over how they choose to ask their questions, and if they choose to do a terrible job then that is entirely their problem - not the concern of curators.
Your question is ultimately your responsibility.

"It is always the duty of the user posting a question to ensure that question complies with the Stack Overflow rules" there are a bunch of rules that are written in the bowels of meta, that users are also supposed to know, yet, there's no effort into making sure that those are intuitive. No one will ever read meta, and meta folks need to understand that. When I asked my first question I only read the help center article that was linked on the ask section. I didn't go to other articles because I didn't have to. The system should present the user with the information needed for them to succeed.

While I don't necessarily disagree with the point you're making, this post still deserves my downvote because it's extremely condescending.

If it doesn't, that a failure of both the rules and the system.

Then, it may be not the duty of curators to "babysit" anything, but it's definitely the duty of moderators to be fair and don't just punish other users for not knowing rules that aren't clearly presented to them.

"It is not the duty of curators to hand-hold and babysit and beg and cajole and vainly hope that a user will panel-beat their train wreck of a question into something answerable." Ignoring the condescending nature of this... is this not the very purpose of the staging ground?

Anyways - if you hate this model, there's no need to engage with it. You can turn off SG popups in the questions lists. Besides, no Staging Ground reviewer is ever expected to do more than leave a comment - improving a post is still largely the asker's responsibility, and the reviewers are just there as guides.
